# No audio input device on ubuntu 13.10 with front-mic plugged-in

Tags: sound, 13.10, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have sound but can't see any audio-input (mic) device in settings.
The mic works, I have tested using `gnome-alsamixer` by redirecting the mic to output.

But when I try the sound recorder it says *"your audio capture settings are incorrect"*.
Also Google-talk plugin says I have mic problems.

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 0: ALC883 Analog [ALC883 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 2: ALC883 Alt Analog [ALC883 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

[image: screenshot]

## UPDATES

1. The rear mic is detected, and works, the problem remains with the
   front-mic.
2. I also use front and back plugs at the same time, and it seems to be a detection problem, the front speakers work (at the same time and channel with rear), just the front-mic doesn't. Can the mic be set to be always on?

Comment: Try pavucontrol

Answer (score 1):

I would try 2 things:

1. Unplugging and plugging the microphone.
2. try restarting pulseaudio with `killall pulseaudio` in terminal

Comment: just tried 1. & 2. , no change with both : sound-recorder still same error and the "Record sound from" listing remains empty

Comment: The firs gave me and idea, so I plugged it in the rear and it works. Now how do I make it detect the front-mic, or make it skip the autodetect?

Comment: I got no idea why it wouldn't detect the front plug. Mine detects it fine. :(

Comment: updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I used `pavucontrol` to change the input device to the front mic instead of the rear mic.

Comment: so you can't have both set at the same time ?

Comment: or you just manually switch each time you plug a mic ?

Comment: The GUI in `pavucontrol` does not allow selecting both at the same time. Indeed I manually switch each time.